# iOS 14 Widgets: How to create different layouts for every widget size family?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I want to create different layouts for each widget size (i.e. small, medium, large). How can I branch my code according to widget's size?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `WidgetFamily` ([Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetfamily)) enum as part of `WidgetKit` will allow you to switch upon the various sizes within your view and adjust accordingly. Set this as an `@Environment` variable and switch on the avaliable cases:

- `.systemSmall`
- `.systemMedium`
- `.systemLarge`

```
struct WidgetView : View {
   @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        
        switch family {
        case .systemSmall:
            Text("Small")
        case .systemMedium:
            Text("Medium")
        case .systemLarge:
            Text("Large")
        default:
            Text("Some other WidgetFamily in the future.")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: in my case i should write like this `@SwiftUI.Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family`

Comment: This is always returning `.systemMedium`, any ideas why?

Comment: The doc says "Use this value to retrieve the widget size that the user chose for a widget." I will assume then it's only after the widgets lands on screen but even after it's still medium for me using context provided from timeline works fine tho! Please update the accepted answer to avoid confusion for future readers! (I'm writing about iOS 15 not sure of the behavior for upcoming iOS 16)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/widgetfamily

Comment: I like to store the bits of my UI that change in separate variables of `some View` so that the resulting content is easier to read :) No need to for single object examples like the one above, of course, but it does keep your code looking neat and helps to prevent nasty pyramids of doom.

Answer (score 9):

Additionally to the accepted answer, in your Provider class methods (*getTimeline, getSnapshot & placeholder*) you get a *context* object which has a *family* member var.

*family* can be one of the three widget sizes: *.systemSmall, .systemMedium & .systemLarge*

Apple's [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetfamily).

Comment: Thanks! In my case only the family from `context` works, and the accepted answer approach doesn't